# Linear programming problem neither max nor min

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Heres the actual question:

> television provider broadcasts two movie channels, A and B. Channel A broadcasts 1 romantic
>   movie, 3 action movies and 3 comedies per month at a cost of 50 Euro. Channel B broadcasts
>   3 romantic movies, 4 action movies and 1 comedy per month at a cost of 25 Euro. Suppose that
>   you like to see 8 romantic movies, 19 action movies and 7 comedies at minimal cost in the coming
>   months. For how many months should you request both channels?
>
> a. Formulate this problem as an LP problem

Now my way of thinking was that I would first write it down more clearly, A and B are the television channels.

$A: 1R,3A,3C => 50 euro$

$B: 3R, 4A, 1C => 25 euro$

And I would define a new variable $x_i :=$ cost of taking a channel one month.

But then I stumble upon the problem of defining the hard limits they have set, the 8 R, 19 A, and  7 C.

In short: how do I define a constraint that is hard (e.g. not a maximum)

Comment: They have not set *limits*, they have set *minimums*. That is, your channel allocation must make *at least* 8 romantic movies, *at least* 19 action movies, and *at least* 7 comedies available to you.

Comment: and you want to be as close to the numbers given as possible of course.. cause you may not be able to EXACTLY get 8,19,7... thanks!

Comment: No, the did not say that you must be "as close to the numbers given" as possible. It said you must exceed the minimums at lowest cost. That's not the same! It's very important never to read more into a model than is being asked.

Comment: That's what I meant yes, I should have said more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I'd just give you hints but I actually have a couple of problems with the problem formulation. First of all, the proper model here is *not* a linear program (LP), but an *integer* linear program (IP). I'm assuming that you cannot subscribe to fractional months, after all, since that is standard practice in the cable industry. This is the model I'm thinking of:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & 50 A + 25 B \\
\text{subject to} & A + 3 B \geq 8 \\
                  & 3 A + 4 B \geq 19 \\
                  & 3 A + B \geq 7 \\
                  & A, B \geq 0 \\
                  & A, B ~ \text{integer}
\end{array}$$
Now of course, it's possible they're permitting you to subscribe to fractional months. But you'd better ask the person requesting the model if that's the case. If they *do* allow fractional months, then indeed you can go ahead and drop the integer constraint, and you have an LP. (LATE EDIT: actually, fractional months really don't make sense, because then you'd get fractional *movies*!)

But even this is not enough, because this only tells you the total number of months to subscribe to A and B, *not* the number of months you must subscribe to both channels. To answer *that* question, you need more information than is provided. Specifically, you need to know the maximum number of months you are allowed to wait to complete your movie watching task.

For instance, suppose the model yields $A=3$, $B=2$. If you're allowed to take 5 months to watch the movies on your list, then you don't need to subscribe to both channels at the same time *ever*. Just subscribe to A for three months, then switch to B.

On the other hand, if you're given an *additional* rule that you must subscribe for a minimum number of total months, then of course the total number of months required is $\max\{A,B\}$, and the number of months subscribed to both channels is $\min\{A,B\}$. But again, without additional information, the answer cannot be given---and *neither* answer is obtained directly from the LP or IP model, but rather from *post processing* the model output.

So the task "Formulate this problem as an LP problem" is, actually, ill-posed. Not only does it likely require an IP, but it requires additional modeling work after the optimization model is solved. "Solve this problem using an LP" would be OK, if they make it clear that fractional months are permitted.

Comment: I presume they're assuming you can subscribe to both channels at the same time and that you want your amount of months to be as low as possible.

Comment: You can presume that, indeed! But that's bad modeling practice. The right thing to do is to go to the person making the request and ask them to supply the missing information required to disambiguate. It can be costly in practice if you make the wrong assumption!

Comment: Very true indeed, it should be as unambiguous as possible. Though in this case seeing as it is the beginning of the course we could go for the least complex solution.

Comment: Fair enough. Depending upon how forward you are, you might offer the instructor my criticism of their problem formulation. :-)

Comment: I think I will, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$min \quad 50A + 25B$

Such that

$A + 3B \geq 8$

$3A + 4B \geq 19$

$3A + B \geq 7$

$A,B\geq 0$

Comment: why $\geq$ ? shouldnt it be (for the first line
$A+3B \leq 8$ ? they cant be more surely.

Comment: Because if you would be subscribed to channels that together broadcast for instance more than 8 romantic movies, you still have the possibility to decide to just watch 8. If they broadcast less than 8, you don't have this possibility.

Comment: Yup I get it thanks. I did the same thing but without $\geq$. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing :) .